# How to get access to browser GUI on linux using something like VNC (docker standalone ff and regular ff))

Tags: linux, selenium, webdriver, vnc

Let say I have a bunch of Selenium tests which I run on Linux and Firefox. 
Now, I have some problem with them and I would like to see the FF GUI to investigate the issue. Is there a possibility to connect to the server i.e using VNC Viewer to have vision on my tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **docker-selenium** for your browser (Firefox, Chrome). It supports VNC to get the recording. More info [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).

Comment: I run docker with standalone-firefox-debug but I have installed 'normal' firefox as well. Now, when I run my tests they go on 'normal' firefox' instead of docker firefox-debug. Is there a trick to force the system to start my tests using docker or I should uninstalled my 'normal' ff and leave only docker? Can you help plese @Boni

Comment: You need to change the way you instantiate your WebDriver object (i.e. using Selenium Grid, where the server is located in the container). You can take a look [here](http://testdetective.com/selenium-grid-with-docker/).

Comment: But I don't want to use Selenium Grid. I just need a particular FF :(